# how to remove the last part of a string based on a condition in scala

Tags: string, scala

i have a string

```
"108.0.5359.124"
```

i want to remove the string's last part from the dot
like this
`"108.0.5359"` i don't want to hard code Istrin just want the string before the last dot every time whatever the string is the format will remain same

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems did you encounter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split`, then `dropRight(1)` (drop the last elem) and `mkString` back to string:

```scala
val s = "108.0.5359.124"
val ss = s.split('.').dropRight(1).mkString(".")

println(ss) //108.0.5359
```

Answer (score 1):

`String` has the method `replaceAll(regex,replacement)`. You could use a [Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to catch the numbers after a dot and set that you want the string ends with that. Using `\d` is for saying that you want to match only digits from **0** to **9**. Then you could use the `+` symbol to say that you want minimum **1** of that char sequence and finally use `$` to say to that is the end of the string. So, in this case you want to replace that part with an empty string. You should do something like

```scala
"108.0.5359.124".replaceAll("\\.\\d+$","")
```

regular expressions are very powerful when you want to work with strings. You also have https://pythex.org/ which is a web that lets you test regex against a text